# Change of Variables nonsense

Tags: calculus

Hopefully someone can clear up this confusion and give me a proper definition for the following.

An author writes "we consider the family of transformations"

$x_{\epsilon}^* = \Phi(x,u,\epsilon)$

$u_{\epsilon}^* = \Psi(x,u,\epsilon)$

Where $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are differentiable with respect to $\epsilon$ and

$x_{0}^* = \Phi(x,u,0) = x$

$u_{0}^* = \Psi(x,u,0) = u$

Then we replace $u$ by $u(x)$ and eliminate $x$ from the resulting equations to obtain the equation $$u_{\epsilon}^* = u_{\epsilon}^*(x^*)$$ (I don't understand this. Is he just saying that $u^*$ is a function of $x^*$)?

and get $$u_{\epsilon}^*(x_{\epsilon}^*) - u(x) = \epsilon \psi(x) + o(\epsilon),$$ 
where $\psi(x) = \frac{\partial \Psi(x,u(x),\epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon} |_{\epsilon = 0}$

He does not define $u_{\epsilon}^*(x_{\epsilon}^*)$ but I take it to mean $u_{\epsilon}^*(x_{\epsilon}^*) = \Psi(x_{\epsilon}^*,u(x_{\epsilon}^*),\epsilon).$ For this definition the above equation which includes $o(\epsilon)$ cannot be true since it should read $\psi(x) = \frac{\partial \Psi(x_{\epsilon}^*,u(x_{\epsilon}^*),\epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon} |_{\epsilon = 0}$ by Taylor's theorem.

Is my definition wrong or is this author just writing garbage?

Comment: Who is this author? A better tag for this would be Lie Groups. We are discussing a Lie Group of point transformations correct?

Comment: Should that be $x_0^* = \Phi(x,u,0) = x$ and $u_0^* = \Psi(x,u,0) = u$?

Comment: @StevenGregory yes thank you.

Comment: This is from Gelfand Calculus of Variations. There is no mention of any Lie groups.

Comment: Oh, so you are studying section 20 "Noether's Theorem".

Comment: The word "Lie Groups" isn't mentioned in that section but that is the underlying structure. If you are interested I would look further into Lie Groups and especially how they are used to solve differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

We could make the change of variables as follows. I believe we are assuming that the group multiplication for the one-parameter group is given by addition. 
$x^{*}=\Phi(x,u,\epsilon)$,
$u^{*}=\Psi(x,u,\epsilon)$
We could invert both relationships 
$x=\Phi(x^{*},u^{*},-\epsilon)$,
$u=\Psi(x^{*},u^{*},-\epsilon)$
Now if we take $u$ to be a function of $x$, $u=u(x)$. Then we use
$$u^{*}=\Psi(x,u(x),\epsilon)$$
and 
$$x=\Phi(x^{*},u^{*},-\epsilon)$$

$$u^{*}=\Psi(\Phi(x^{*},u^{*},-\epsilon),u(\Phi(x^{*},u^{*},-\epsilon)),\epsilon)$$
This then defines an implicit relation between $u^{*}$ and $x^{*}$